# How can I manage public records and user specific records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controllers

I have a situation where a company is managed by a user. i.e.: A user can create, read, update and delete their own companies. But I'd also like that same user to access a list of all companies in the system, even when logged out.

e.g.:

user_a manages the following companies: company_a and company_b

user_b manages the following companies: company_c and company_d

user_a should be able to see a list of his own companies (a and b) as well as a list of all companies (a, b, c, and d)

What's the best way to handle this in the controllers?

Idealy, I'd like to have it setup under 2 separate routes as follows:

```
/companies
/users/1/companies
```

Should I have one controller for companies, or multiple? and how would that work?

I'm looking for best practices in this type of scenario.

Comment: Possible Routing approach can be:

`resources :users
 resources :companies
end
match '/companies' => 'companies#public_list', :as => :public_companies_list`

So you can use one UsersController and once CompaniesController.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is actually the answer I like the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO if all user can see all companies it's perfect to have one controller to get this job. Just in template you can check if current user is author of specified company and then add link to edit this company etc. if you want of course.

Comment: I'd like to show the user two separate lists, though. One for their companies only, and the other for all companies. I'm doing this because the list of companies could be very large.

Comment: It'd be nice to have two separate routes as follows:
/companies and /users/1/companies

Comment: So you want 3 pages: two list (user companies and paginated all companies list), only user companies, and all companies (with pagination too)?

Comment: one controller with three actions (per page) and two private methods for retrieve user companies and all companies.

Comment: So the actions in the companies controller would be index and user_index and private methods to load_resource or something?

Comment: Now I would say that @thesis gave better answer in comment.

Answer (score 1):

In your situation approach can be:

1. Use `Devise` RubyGem to handle authentication. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
2. Create or Scaffold simple CompaniesController with RESTful actions set: `index, new, create, edit, udpate, destroy` actions.
3. Add `before_filter` in `CompaniesController` to restrict access to action which require user authentication:

   before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:public_list]
4. You should have `has_many` assosiation between User and Company ActiveRecord models, to access companies collection of `current_user`.

**Here goes example code:**

Routing:

```
resources :users do
    resources :companies
end
match '/companies' => 'companies#public_list', :as => :public_companies_list
```

Controller:

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:public_list]


  def index
    @companies = current_user.companies
  end

  def show
    @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @company = current_user.companies.new
  end

  def edit
    @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @company = current_user.companies.new(params[:company])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.save
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
        format.html { redirect_to @company, notice: 'Company was successfully updated.' }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @company = current_user.companies.find(params[:id])
    @company.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to companies_url }
    end
  end
end
```

For public companies list add this method:

```
def public_list
  @companies = Company.all
end
```